# $k$-Taiwan numbers

Tags: nt.number-theory, analytic-number-theory, prime-numbers, goldbach-type-problems

Say a positive composite integer $n$ is a $k$-Taiwan number if $r_{0}(n):=\inf\{r>0,(n-r,n+r)\in\mathbb{P}^{2}\}=p^{k}$ for some prime number $p$, and a Taiwan number if it is a $k$-Taiwan number for some non negative integer $k$.
That way $12$ is a $0$-Taiwan number as $11$ and $13$ make a couple of twin primes, $14$ is a $1$-Taiwan number (as $r_{0}(14)=3$ which is prime), $22$ is a $2$-Taiwan number as $r_{0}(22)=9=3^2$, and so on.

My questions are as follows:

1. are there $k$-Taiwan numbers for every non negative integer $k$?
2. are there infinitely many Taiwan numbers?
3. does one have $r_{0}(n)\ll_{k}\log^{k} n$ as $n$ runs over the $k$-Taiwan numbers?

Comment: For $k=1$ this essentially asks about solutions to $p+2q=r$ in primes. Showing infinitude of those should be within reach of standard methods. I have no idea about larger $k$, and I see no reason why 3 would be true.

Comment: I think the main tricky points for 3 are the cases $k=1$ and $k=2$, as it's trivially true for $k=0$, while Carl Pomerance told me in a private communication some years ago that we expect the inequality $r_{0}(n)\ll\log^{2}n\log\log n$ to hold.